# No input were found in config file when using visual studio 2022 preview

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[image]
my tsconfig.json looks like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

also have a folder called "typescript" where my `home.ts` is in there and when i make changes, it builds a `home.ts` in `wwwroot/js` just fine
Also note that my tsconfig.json and "typescript" folder are siblings and in the root of my project (.net core 6 )

I have tried every combination of include/exclude in every SO posting i fould find and i couldn't get rid of those warnings in the picture, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that tsconfig.json is set to be copied to the output directory. If you change it to Do not copy in File Properties then the error disappears.